# jQuery 1.12 full (CJS/webpack)?

Tags: jquery-ui, webpack, commonjs

jQuery UI 1.12 appears to backwards incompatible with jQuery UI 1.10 (hurray!). They've shuffled all their code around and now their "main" bundle only includes `$.widget` but not the actual widgets like `$.datepicker`.

Specifically, inside `package.json` you'll find

```
"main": "ui/widget.js",
```

This tells build tools like webpack where to find the main file for inclusion. However, `ui/widget.js` doesn't include the rest of the components like it did before.

Normally this isn't such a big deal, and I can just hack around it by modifying my `webpack.config.js` to point to the *real* main file, except that I can't find it!

*Is* there a main/bundle file included in the [npm version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui) of jQuery 1.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pull request's discussion gave me the information I needed.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/1600

What I learned is with jquery-ui 1.12.0, there's no more main file that imports everything. In my case I only needed either ui/widget.js or the button widget (jquery-ui/ui/widgets/button). I pointed to them directly and it worked for me.

In your case, you should be fine requiring your datepicker like this:

```
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker');
```

It's kinda good actually. You don't need to bundle all of jquery-ui to inherit one component you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to have to create my own index file now with all the widgets listed, because I have no idea what's actually in use in my monolithic app.